# FxLayout Custom Breakpoint Directive correct usage

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I have successfully followed this guide [BreakPoints · angular/flex-layout Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Breakpoints) to create a breakpoint `(max-width: 768px)` and created an alias for it `xs.ipad`

The guide had me set up a directive which I followed and used the selector `[fxHide.xs.ipad]`

If I place this on a HTML element the element is hidden under 768px. Great.

But I want to use `fxHide fxShow.xs.ipad` to show a message only on screen width's smaller than this custom breakpoint.

If I change the selector to fxShow.xs.ipad in the directive then this works BUT I want to have both selector's available. I'm sure I don't need to create another directive just for the fxShow so my question is how do I set up my directive so both selectors will work?

**custom.breakpoints.ts**

```
import { BREAKPOINT } from "@angular/flex-layout";

const IPADPORTRAIT_BREAKPOINT = {
  alias: 'xs.ipad',
  suffix: 'XsIpad',
  mediaQuery: '(max-width: 768px)',
  overlapping: false
};

export const CustomBreakPointsProvider = {
  provide: BREAKPOINT,
  useValue: IPADPORTRAIT_BREAKPOINT,
  multi: true
};
```

**breakpoint.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive} from '@angular/core';
import { ShowHideDirective } from '@angular/flex-layout';

const selector = `[fxHide.xs.ipad]`;
const inputs = ['fxHide.xs.ipad'];

@Directive({selector, inputs})
export class BreakpointDirective extends ShowHideDirective {
  protected inputs = inputs;
}
```

I'm new to directives, I've tried removing the `fxHide` and just having `xs.ipad` but that does not work.

**Required outcome**

```
<div fxHide.xs.ipad>
   <h1>This will be viewable on everything wider than iPad portrait</h1>
</div>

<div fxHide fxShow.xs.ipad>
   <h1>This will be viewable only on screens smaller than iPad Portrait</h1>
</div>
```